# Use multiple cores to perform Python computations?

Tags: python

I am on a HPC that has 24 cores available. When I run my Python program, `top` tells me `100% CPU`, which I think means it is using only one core! How may I let Python use multiple cores?

Major computations are happening in an optimization function call, which I can't go inside and modify. There is no for loop either, so parallezing the loop is not really an option.

As such, I want to just use `Process` in the hope that the OS can somehow accelerate the execution by using multiple cores. Here is my attempt.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
p = Process(target=main, args=(myArgs))
p.start()
p.join()
```

But `top` still says `100% CPU`. :-(

Comment: There is no magic in multiprocessing. You simply run `main` in a new process while the main process waits for it to finish. If you started more processes they might be distributed over different cores. But there is not much point in running a function multiple times (in parallel) unless it is designed to split the work.

Comment: You can not just parallelize your process like that. The GIL prevents I think that multiple threads are executed natively and clash when trying to access the same Python object concurrently. That means, if you want to use more than one core you have to identify parts of your code that are suited for parallelization and e.g. write a function that processes an independent batch. Then you could process 24 batches at a time for example.

Comment: @Tristan Processes do not share the GIL.

Comment: Multiprocessing works by running different parts of the program that don't depend on each other on separate parts of the computer (sort of, it's pretty complicated).  You would need to rewrite the program to parallelize it.

Comment: @kazemakase I see, but how do I `start more processes`?. Like I said, major computations that I want accelerated are all in one function.

Comment: For your question in the comment above, just create a list comprehension of processes, with each item in that list being supplied its own chunk of data, then iterate that list and start them all. That's assuming that the data to be processed can be chunked independently and you can combine the output of each process into a single output at the end.

Comment: You can't just run one function and wish that it were already split into multiple parallel functions for you. If you could, then why would you need Process? It would already be fully parallel when you run it from the main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original code starts only one process. That is why only one core is used. To start multiple processes:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
n = 3
procs = []
for _ in range(n):
    procs.append(Process(target=main, args=(myArgs)))
    procs[-1].start()
for p in procs:
    p.join()
```

However, this is unlikely to improve anything. What happens is that `main` runs 3 times in parallel, 3 times doing the same thing.

The `main` function will need to be written to be aware that it runs multiple time in parallel so it can split the work between invocations. This requires non-trivial process synchronization techniques.

Comment: But major computations that I want accelerated are all in one function that I can't go in and modify. So there will be no way for me to use multiple cores?

Comment: @SibbsGambling There may be a way.  It depends on how you use the function. It can work if you run it multiple times with different input data and it generates indepentent output data for each input.

Answer (score 0):

You just fork a process and join to wait for terminating it. You can see two process in top or ps, the main process is idle while the child process is working in 100% cpu.

If you want all cores work, you should fork multiple sub processes and join them one by one, or easier, just use a pool.

A example for that:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
processes = []
for args in args_list:
    p = Process(target=main, args=(args, ))
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)
for p in processes:
    p.join()
```

Here is a short example for pool:

```
import multiprocessing

def add(args):
    return sum(args)

pool_size = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=pool_size)

inputs = [(1, 2)] * 100

outputs = pool.map(add, inputs)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: Does this work because one pool worker can work on `add(100)` and the other can work on `add(200)`? If so, it's not gonna work in my case, where the computation are not parallel in nature.

Comment: If the computation cannot parallel, how can it run on multi cores at same time? You should split your computation into pieces not depends on each other first.